# How to design the content of a UIScrollView in a nib easily

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a scrollview which has to display a view larger than the available display area. 
I want to easily design the user interface without moving the embedded view up and down every time I have to do some changes. 
The problem is everything outside the visible area is invisible in IB.

Is there any switch or trick to make everything visible in IB?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### UPDATE

I have posted [another solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16889377/77567) which I think is simpler and better, and works in storyboards.

#### ORIGINAL

Create your scroll view in the nib with the appropriate superview, position, and size.

Next, create a *completely separate, top-level* `UIView` instance by dragging a `UIView` out of the palette and dropping it into the work area outside of any existing views.  In the Attributes inspector, set the Size popup to “None” and make sure the Status Bar, Top Bar, and Bottom Bar are all set to None.  Here's an example:

[image: setting up content view]

This new top-level view will be your content view.  Give your view controller two outlets: `scrollView` and `contentView`:

```
@interface MyViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;

@end
```

In the nib, wire up the `scrollView` outlet to the scroll view and wire up the `contentView` outlet to the content view.

Build your content view hierarchy inside the content view.  Set its size as large as you need - it can be larger than 320x480 (as long as you have set all of its bars to None).

In your view controller's `viewDidLoad`, add `contentView` as a subview of `scrollView` and set `scrollView.contentSize` to the size of `contentView`:

```
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
@synthesize contentView = _contentView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureScrollView];
}

- (void)configureScrollView {
    CGSize size = self.contentView.bounds.size;
    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = size;

    // If you don't use self.contentView anywhere else, clear it here.
    self.contentView = nil;
    // If you use it elsewhere, clear it in `dealloc` and `viewDidUnload`.
}
```

Comment: I didi as you said but its not giving me any handle to resize the UIView. Can you please explain how to resized the UIView. if view cant be resized its the same having another controller. please help.

Comment: @rob : I appreciate that little animated pic that is so cool. But I dont know I am simple dont able to drop the view in. As soon I let got the click its just comes back from editing area to list again.

Comment: @Alix I deduce that you are using a storyboard.  This technique does not work in a storyboard, because (as of iOS 6.1) storyboards do not support editing top-level views in any useful way.

Comment: @rob : thanks a lot. I figured out that last night too. Its kind of sad as its real pain when designing the scroll view. :( :'(

Comment: You can create a separate xib to hold your content view and have your view controller load it in code.  You just won't be able to create any segues from the objects in the xib.