# How to handle long view in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

So I want to have a different type of custom cell but my problem is how can I add more if there is not enough space in a certain view in story board.

E.G.
[image: Sample UI]

Comment: In storyboard: Select `YourViewController` > `Attribute Inspector` > change size `inferred to Freeform` and set height as per your requirement in `size inspector` .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16889377/77567

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select your view controller, and in the fourth tab of InterfaceBuilder, select 'freeform' in size.

[image]

OR

Inside the UIStoryboard, you can simply select your UIViewController and go directly to the fifth tab. Just change the Simulated Size from Fixed to Freeform .

[image]

It works for you

Comment: Thanks for the pic :D

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks to Bhavin Ramani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4078527/bhavin-ramani) that answer is:

In storyboard: Select **YourViewController > Attribute Inspector** > change size inferred to **Freeform** and set height as per your requirement in size inspector

Answer (score 0):

Choose your details view controller in storyboard, show it's size inspector and set it's simulated size to Freeform.